# Is there a way to re-order the columns in SQLite-manager?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have a .csv-document with a lot of data. It has 71 different columns.

Now I want to import this data to Core Data. But when I create the attributes in xcdatamodel the attributes sorts by its name, and not in the order that I want them to be. So when the .sqlite-file is created, the columns is in the wrong order. I've tried to order them in SQLite-manager, but when I reopen the .sqlite the columns is in the same order as before the change.

Is there a way to re-order the columns in SQLite-manager?

Answer (score 1):

Well, 71 columns is a lot. Since you're using Core Data, I'd suggest trying to denormalize a little bit. Core Data is not a tabular database. That said, I'd suggest keeping track of the current column, and storing the data in an array. Then, you separate the data into NSManagedObjects as necessary.

**EDIT:**

Let's pretend that your sqlite database had three columns in this order: `firstName`, `lastName`, `middleInitial`. Now imagine that your CSV file had them in a different order, like `lastName`, `middleInitial`, `firstName` . You *could* reorder the CSV file or the sqlite file, but since you're using Core Data, you can do this another way.

You're going to have an entity with all of your properties. In my example, it's the "Person" entity. So, we go ahead and create an instance of this Person entity.

```
Person *newPerson = [[Person alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Now, you need to maintain a reference to this `Person` instance so that you can access it when parsing your CSV. I recommend Dave DeLong's [CHCSVParser library](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser). Essentially, it allows event-based parsing of CSV files.

When you hit a new field, check which field number it is. You can do this by keeping a currentField variable around, resetting it to zero when you hit a new line, and incrementing on every field. Now, when you hit a field, if the number is 0, or the first field, you set `newPerson.lastName`. If it's the second field, you assign `newPerson.middleInitial`. And, if you hit the third field, you set `newPerson.firstName`. The idea is that you can assign persistent properties without touching the sqlite database. If you're using Core Data, this is the way to go.

Comment: The .csv-document has more than 2000 posts and 71 different values. Because the Core Data has made the .sqlite columns in a special order, I need to change them in order for the data from the .csv-document to come in the right order. I thought this was going to be easy by just dragging the columns in SQLite-Manager in the order that I wanted, but when I re-open the .sqlite-file the old order is present. Isn't there an easy way to change the order in SQLite-manager?

Comment: You don't want to import directly into sqlite if you're using core data. Use NSManagedObjects instead. You don't need to care about order than.

Comment: I solved the problem in another way. I changed the order of the columns in the .csv-file with Excel instead, then imported the .csv-file into the .sqlite-file and then the .sqlite-file to my project. Works like a charm!

Thanks for your help Moshe, but I don't know if I understood your answer though. The problem was that I had an .csv-file with loads of data stored in a specific way. I wanted to import the file without having to insert all the data manually, which would've taken forever. I don't understand how I should do this in an easy way through Core Data and NSManagedObjects?

Comment: You're not supposed to modify sqlite databases created by Core Data because they often have proprietary fields. I'll edit my answer with an example.